# Unable to clone git repository: foo.git/info/refs not found

Tags: centos, git

I tried to clone a git repository using the command:

```
git clone http://git.denx.de/cgi­bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u­boot.git;a=summary
```

but I got the error:

> fatal: http://git.denx.de/cgi­bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u­boot.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: The URI you want is this : git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git . Also, don't do development work as root.

Comment: @shaiba : don't see any evidence here that anyone is doing anything as root, git certainly does not require that.

Comment: @goldilocks I removed it when I [edited](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/64560/revisions) the post; it originally had the line "Initialized empty Git repository in /root/Desktop/gitweb.cgi?p=u­boot/.git/"

Answer (score 3):

That error can happen if you give `git` a path that isn't a git repo. According to the [homepage](http://git.denx.de/):

> To clone one of these trees using Git type:
>
> ```
> git clone git://git.denx.de/<project_name>  <your_repository_name>/
> ```
>
> Cloning per HTTP is also supported (just replace git:// with http:// in the examples above). Note that native git transfer is much faster and more robust. Use HTTP only if you have no other choice.

And the project listed on that page is named "u-boot.git". So you want to do one of these:

```
git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
git clone http://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
```